# Static root page on Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to set up a static landing page for a google appengine application. However I get 404 when I go to the root of the site. It works fine locally just doesn't work when I deploy it. The app.html page work so its just the landing page thats not working.

Here's something from  app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /rest/.*
  script: main.py
  login: required

- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js

- url: /
  static_files: static\index.html
  upload: static\index.html

- url: /app.html
  static_files: static/app.html
  upload: static/app.html
  login: required

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change those backslashes to forward-slashes.
Should be:

```
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html
```

[Backslashes are escape characters](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).
So you were specifying a path that doesn't exist.